# How to send feedback email using malto in compose multiplatform in iOS part?

Tags: ios, iphone, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform

I've been struggling with sending feedback email. I tried the expect actual concept as I didn't find any trustworthy library for the task.

In the android section its fine using the below code:

```
val body = """
 ----------start-----------------
 Please don't remove this information
 Info............
 -----------end-----------------
 """
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("mailto:"))
    intent.putExtra(
        Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
        arrayOf("abcd@gmail.com")
    )
    intent.putExtra(
        Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
        "app-issue"
    )
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body)
    startActivity(LocalContext.current,intent,null)
```

But in the iOS part, I've done such but I didn't have any present method in the ios.kt file.

```
if (MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()) {
        val  mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mail.setToRecipients(listOf("abcd@gmail.com"))
        mail.setSubject("app-issue")

        val deviceInfo = """
    ----------start-----------------
    Please don't remove this information
    Info......
    -----------end-----------------
    """

        mail.setMessageBody(deviceInfo, isHTML = false)

    } else {
        // show failure alert
    }
```

So how to open the default mail client in the iOS platform with these informations.

I also looked up at [this code](https://gist.github.com/ChrisMash/e1630095a9cabf766c70bb5573d726fa) but URLComponents are not also referenced in the class.